# Can you order videos in windows explorer by last played / accessed?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

I have a bunch of videos in a folder, I would like to know which ones I have watched and when, so I can revisit old ones or watch ones I have not seen yet etc.

I tried adding date accessed but all the date times were the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows stores several dates with each file (on drives with NTFS). Windows Explorer usually just shows the 'Last Modified' date. You can display other file properties by
right clicking the column headers in Explorer and then click on 'More...'. There you can check  "Date Accessed" to see the 'last accessed date'.

That's the theory. **In practice that does not work**, the date shown is usually the same as the 'last modified' date.

The reason why this does not work is that updating each file when it is accessed takes time and would slow down your OS.

So by default Microsoft disabled the update of the "Date Accessed" property.

Open the Registry with regedit.exe and navigate to:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
```

There is a value '**NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate**' that is usually set to 1, meaning this update of the date is disabled. You can change this to 0 to enable it. After rebooting your
machine Windows will now update the 'accessed date' property on files. You can test this by
just open a text file without editing it and you'll see a fresh "Date Accessed".

This doesn't really help you with your videos because when you last watched them, this feature was disabled.

Unless you really, really need that date, I would recommended to leave that feature turned off.

Related questions:

- [The last access date is not changed even after reading the file on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/251263/the-last-access-date-is-not-changed-even-after-reading-the-file-on-windows-7)
- [Are there any negative effects when disabling last access timestamp?](https://superuser.com/questions/200126/are-there-any-negative-effects-when-disabling-last-access-timestamp)

Comment: Excellent information there. I am almost tempted to give it a go just to see how it'd perform but i wont :)

Answer (score 0):

Right click the column headers and click on "More" ... add a check next to "Date Accessed" column... hit ok... then click the column to sort it.

Comment: Cite: *> I tried adding date accessed but all the date times were the same.*