# Is there an equivalent of the Unix touch command on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, file-permissions

On Unix the `touch` command allows you to change the date of creation of a file. I would like to know whether there is an analogous command on Windows 7 which would allow you to change the dates and times of creation, last modification, and last access to a file, and would also like to know whether there is a way to do the same from the standard Windows 7 operating system graphical interface utilities.

NOTE: when I go to the Properties for a file by right-clicking on it I see the dates and times of creation and last modification but not the date and time the last (read-only) access to the file took place.

Comment: I can see the accessed time. Note that the access time is not regularily updated. See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/200126/are-there-any-negative-effects-of-disabling-the-last-access-timestamp) and note that updating is disabled on Windows 7 by default.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/251470/ and http://superuser.com/questions/10426/ cover some of this ground, too.