# Sorting by Date - Very Slow

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8, sorting

I'm using Windows 8 RTM. I have about 1,100 files in a folder. When I sort by date (in either direction), The address bar shows the green progress indicator as if it's working hard to perform the sort. This should be near instant - why is it taking so long? It takes probably 2 minutes just to sort these files by date! (This was instant in Windows 7.)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Which Date column is this exactly? As mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/335901/138343), **Date** is different from **Date Created/Modified/Accessed** (on Win7 at least, ought to be the same in Win8 as well). It might be slow if the former column type is used and Explorer is trying to extract EXIF data from the files. Try **Date Created** or **Date Modified** instead and see if it is still as slow. (If it is, check your HDD for errors using the manufacturer's utility.)

Comment: You're right. It was just "Date" - no more info there! This is in my Downloads folder but it seems that Windows may have been treating it as a folder containing images/videos/etc. and was attempting to extract the "Date" from some internal mechanism depending on the file type. Changing to "Date created" works much better. Thanks.

Comment: You can also probably [change the folder's template](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9278-folder-template-change-windows-8-a.html).

Comment: Nice. It was set to Pictures - changed it back to General. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Dude you just saved me 5 minutes sorting a folder full of media files!

Comment: This has been plaguing me for at least a year. Thank you!

Comment: THANK YOU! I can't believe Windows even has this as such an easy to stumble into option, it performs so terribly it makes many folders on my machine unusable.