# Folder takes a long time to sort by date modified every time

Tags: ssd, windows-explorer, sorting

I have a screenshots folder that is sorted by date modified. Every time I open up this folder to retrieve a recent screenshot, it takes 5-10 seconds to sort it. Is there a way to make this instantaneous? I am using an SSD.

Comment: How many files are in your screenshots folder?

Comment: I've noticed the same behavior -- more with the dialogs than the Explorer view. I think it may have be related to displaying thumbnails.

Comment: they are thumbnail view and 2000 items.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting by Date - Very Slow](https://superuser.com/questions/487647/sorting-by-date-very-slow)