# Why is the Date column sometimes the Date Taken column, but 12 hours ahead?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, date

In an effort to find an answer to [my other question](https://superuser.com/q/1552703/138676), I came across this unusual behavior.

Sometimes the Date column is a copy of the Date Taken column, down to the minute, but exactly 12 hours ahead. **What is an explanation for this?**

This is happening to .MOV files taken on an Iphone 4S then transferred to the computer.

[image]

Comment: What file system does the original device use?  What time zone is that device set to compared to the unknown OS in the screenshot?

Comment: @Ramhound I've added that to the question. Timezone would be CST.

Comment: The difference likely is due to Unix timestamp, I suspect, the rest of the meta data is simply being modified when the file is created on the Windows machine.  This would be within scope on the appropriate Apple Stack Exchange more than likely.